# Would you say 'Google is' or 'Google are'?

Tags: grammar

Would you use the third person singular or third person plural when referring to an organisation like Google?

Comment: ***I*** say Google ***is*** working on ...  But many people at work say things like “Google ***have*** just released...” and it just sounds so wrong.  But I suppose it must sound equally wrong to them when I speak.

Comment: In AmE, organizations are usually referred in the singular. In BrE, most often in the plural.

Answer (score 0):

Since organization have rights similar to individuals, it follows that you would use the singular term.